# How to read the entire page html data(including text inout) using jQuery as plain text

Tags: jquery

http://code.google.com/p/expbuilder/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Fcb

I have used the above code to generate the web based query builder.

How to read the entire html content from the built query page?

or in other words, How to read the entire html table(including text and select inputs) data as plain html text. Once I get the entire html text I can process the query criteria.
Thank you,
Smith

Comment: use `.text()` instead of `.html()` ?

Answer (score 1):

use a way like this:

Based on selector ('html, body') or ('.myclass'), ecc...

```
    $('myselector').find('*').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('input')) alert($(this).val());
        if($(this).is('select')) alert($(this).find('option:selected').val());
        if($(this).is('p, div, span')) alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Now by looping through this I can build the query expression.

Comment: @user1492518 perfect, remember to accept or vote answers for the next readers. happy to be useful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firebug or something similar?  You can view the HTML as it changes.

If you are going to use the code programatically, why not go high up the DOM?

```
$('body').html()
```

or

```
$('table').html()
```

Comment: Both of these does not give the value the user entered in the text box and the option selected in the drop down box. How to read these values along with the above data.